# Running two SSIS loop containers in parallel

Tags: sql-server, ssis

In a package I have two loop containers that run fine one after the other. Each has its own variable name used to iterate over and load two different sets of Excel files to the same table. As far as I can tell there is no overlap between the packages so I thought to speed things up by running them in parallel.
When starting the package however (manually in SSIS), the containers look like they execute but then after a few seconds the entire package shows as complete without any errors, and none of the loop containers or subsequent tasks did anything.

The package log only shows validation completed for each of the loop containers.

Is there some switch somewhere to make two loop containers play nicely?

Here is what it looks like:
[image: Screenshot of 'completed' package]

Comment: If you can add some screenshots it will be more clear

Comment: The only explanation I can think of is that you missed something that the two loops share.   But no, there's no "switch".

Comment: If the next task after the branching is disabled or not does not make a difference, for now I only got the containers to run in parallel if they are not connected to any downstream task but clearly that is not very useful. Seems like the problem is not with the containers.

Answer (score 0):

Place the two loops and their corresponding script tasks (via precedence constraints) in a sequence container. Connect the `Create Table` script task to the sequence container. Then connect the sequence container to `D Product Family` data flow.

Note: disabling a task won't affect operation as SSIS will just skip over the disabled task(s) and go to the next one until all tasks have been completed.

Comment: This approach worked once and on the next run not anymore, using the same test files and not changing anything else. This is so weird.

Comment: What folder and file name/type are the two foreach loop containers looping over? Is it possible they are trying to read the same file simultaneously? I HIGHLY doubt this, but leave no stone un-turned.

Comment: Good point but I stoned that turn already, there is no overlap for sure. They happily run side by side as long as no subsequent task is connected, success or completion makes no difference btw.